# Проверки в методах

Tags: java

У меня часто бывают случаи, когда нужно отправить объект как аргумент к методу,
например:

```
User user = getUser();
insertData(user);
```

И запись этого объекта в базу:

```
void insertData(User user){
    if (user != null){
        // записываем в базу
    } else {
        // показываем сообщение
    }
}
```

И это корректно работает.

Но у меня часто возникает вопрос:

А правильно ли делать проверку на `null` объекта в методе для записи, а не до того как вызвать этот метод?

То есть,

```
User user = getUser();

if (user != null){
    insertData(user);
} else {
    // показываем сообщение
}
```

---

```
void insertData(User user){
    // записываем в базу
}
```

**UPD:**

Приведя пример записи в базу, я не категорически имел ввиду запись в базу, любой метод. Работа с файлами, просто методы которые решают задачи.
Например тот же `List<Class> example;`

```
void exampleMethod(List<Example> examList){};
```

**Вопрос:** проверку делать до или в методе?

Comment: На самом деле можно и так и так, всё зависит от логики приложения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверки на валидность до вызова метода обычно не используются, так как это приведет к многократному дублированию кода по валидации перед каждым вызовом метода (из разных мест программы) и вообще сделает код более "грязным". Уместнее проверять корректность данных непосредственно перед их применением (внутри метода).

Что касается именно методов сохранения и тп действий, то валидацию поступивших данных проводят в самом методе, а результат валидации возвращают из метода для вывода всяких сообщений или других действий по решению проблемы.

То есть, в вашем примере, метод проверяет, может ли он записать то, что получил в качестве аргумента и если не может, то не записывает, а из метода возвращает, например, false (или какую то константу, если состояний может быть несколько). Далее, код, который вызывал запись, получает ответ от метода и уже "думает", что с этим делать (например, если пришло false вывести сообщение о неудачной попытке, если true, то подтверждение успешного действия)

но это не универсальное решение для всех случаев и в других действиях такой подход не должен использоваться, то есть в большей части зависит от задачи, решаемой методом. Хорошим примером правильной практики в каждом случае  будут анологичные вашим (по выполняемой работе) методы из API

Answer (score 0):

Я бы рекомендовал до, но в самом методе выбрасывать `NullPointerException` на всякий случай.

В методе вставки в БД не должно быть вывода никаких сообщений и т.п., логика по обработке должна быть в другом месте.

Другой вариант - возвращать из метода о вставке результат операции.

Comment: Какой смысл его выбрасывать самому, если он будет и так выброшен?

Comment: 1) Я не видел самого кода вставки в БД, сложно что-то сказать. 2) Это исключение может быть и по другой причине.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Сложно судить о вашем коде из-за его абстрактности, но в целом так делать неправильно с точки зрения проектирования ПО. Метод, занимающийся вставкой данных в БД не должен ничего знать о пользовательском интерфейсе и о том, как показывать сообщения об ошибках - это не его забота. Такое смешивание логики приводит к связности кода из-за ненужных зависимостей: ваш код работы с данными становится намертво привязан к коду работы с пользовательским интерфейсом из-за того, что в нём используется ненужный ему вывод сообщения. Такой код становится сложнее изменять и тестировать